# Solr full-import technics

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I have one really big SQL query to load all data. It takes too long time to execute. How can I programatically implement full-import feature instead of SQL selection formula?

Comment: what do you mean by subselects ? can you give example ?

Comment: Jayendra, I have updated my question

Comment: do you mean how can you use the sql and feed data to solr instead of using it by DIH ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a couple of views in your db that would partition your data on some attribute. 

But I really don't get the purpose of that? 
Are you using delta imports? That way you only run your huge full import once.